# iOS SDK - Subviews and actions

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have view controller (say VC1) and second view controller (VC2) which has a button (with touchUpInside event , implemented in VC2).
Now, in VC1 I do this:

```
VC2 *vc = [Utils instantiateViewControllerFromMainStoryboard:@"myVC"];
[self.view addSubView:vc.view];
```

But now, when I tap on button which is on VC2 app crashes?! Why?
And how to solve this?

Comment: no one can help you solve this unless you give us more information. A good start would be telling us what the exception says, along with the code where you set up the button in VC2 and the target action method the button is calling

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  Can you post your stack trace and the type of exception being thrown?

Comment: There is no exception in log. It just crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple. The button in the second view controller tries to call a method in `VC2` to handle the event. But as your code is written, the instance of `VC2` is long gone because you never keep a reference to it.

Why are you adding the `view` of the 2nd view controller to the 1st view controller's view? Why not use a navigation controller and push the 2nd view controller into view?

If you need to keep things as they are then you must have the 1st view controller keep a strong reference to the 2nd view controller so it isn't deallocated.